# How to prevent body scrolling when scroll on Drop down menu.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## How to prevent body scrolling when scroll on Drop down menu.? 1

Dear friends,

actually i'm facing problem in my project. [see project](http://creativecaffeine.co/atmof/works_abc-emporio-kan.html)

i did horizontal scrolling on this page. its is working smoothly.
but when i scroll on drop down menu the page also scrolling. is there any option to prevent the page scrolling when mouse hover in drop down menu?

adding the script here which i used for horizontal scroll:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
// By default, swipe is enabled.

 $('section').horizon();

 // If you do not want to include another plugin, TouchSwipe, you can set it to false in the default options by passing in the option as false.
 //$('section').horizon({swipe: false});

 $(document).on('click', '.go-to-2', function () {
    $(document).horizon('scrollTo', 'section-section2');
 });
</script>
```

please help me to find out Any solution...

Comment: Your link shows up as a blocked high risk website. I would recommend that you create a fiddle or post the full code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the text area below `Emporio Kannur...` from scrolling, try adding a `mousewheel` event listener and stop event propagation, so it does not bubble up to the `horizon` jquery plugin.

Something like this:

```
// .work_detail_wraper contains the text you down want to see scrolling
$('.work_detail_wraper') 
  .on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll' , function(e) { 
     e.stopPropagation() 
  })
```

You can also take a look at the [horizon plugin's code](https://github.com/trgraglia/jquery.horizonScroll.js/blob/master/jquery.horizonScroll.js), and adapt it so it doesn't scroll on certain events.

Comment: hi dear friend,

I'm using jquery.horizonScroll.js for horizontal scroll. and that script i mentioned above as supporting in html. 

but when i scroll on dropdown menu the body also scrolling. 

the script you mentioned in comment is not working.

is there any function to include in jquery.horizonScroll.js to disable the mousewheel on hover any div...??

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'stopPropagation()' for this

```
$('.section-section2').scroll(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```